# Docker giving error when writing to external volume

Tags: docker

I am running influxDb image on Windows using Docker for Windows
https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb/

when running via the following command

```
docker run -d -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 --name influxdb influxdb
```

I am writing a massive amount of data (bulks of 10k records) and all is working fine.

I would like however to save the data externally so I'm using:

```
docker run -d -v /c/Users/me/Documents/Docker/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb -p 8083:8083 -p 8086:8086 --name influxdb influxdb
```

I saw that the db was created in my c:/users and was writing data appropriately, 
however from time to time I see in the influxdb logs the following errors:

```
[tsm1] 2016/10/19 07:37:59 error adding new TSM files from snapshot: fsync: invalid argument
[tsm1] 2016/10/19 07:37:59 Snapshot for path /var/lib/influxdb/data/QuotesSnapshotOneMin/autogen/2 written in 788.559316ms
[tsm1] 2016/10/19 07:37:59 error writing snapshot: fsync: invalid argument
```

The db is writing well also with the errors I mentions for while but than it crashes and stops writing. the logs does not indicate anything special besides of the `tsm` I mentioned earlier

What seems to be the issue?

Comment: If you haven't already, can you open an [issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/new) on the InfluxDB repo for this. I suspect this may be an actual issue.